# volume of hyeprcube with sum of coordinates larger than x

Tags: integration, geometry, solid-geometry

Consider an hypercube in $N$ dimensions with one vertex in the origin and another vertex in the point with all coordinates equal to 1, with edges alignes with axes.
Is there a general analytic expression, close form, not in terms of an integral or of an intinite series, for the function $f(x)$ that measures the volume of the part of the hypercube where the sum of the $N$ coordinates is larger than $x$, as a function of $x$ and $N$? In other words

\begin{equation}
f_N(x) = \int_0^1 dx_1 \int_0^1 dx_2 ... \int_0^1 dx_N \Theta\left(x_1+x_2+...+x_n-x\right)
\end{equation}

My first guess would be no, but I am reading on a paper whose result, if correct, would imply a yes to this question.

Comment: What is the proposed result in this paper?

Comment: Something that can be...larger than one. Then they fix it adding a theta function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired volume is naturally equivalent to the probability that the [Irwin–Hall distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) on $N$ $U(0,1)$ random variables is larger than $x$, or equivalently smaller than $N-x$. The CDF is given in the link:
$$P(X\le x)=\frac1{N!}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom Nk(x-k)^N$$
Replace $x$ with $N-x$ and you have your formula.

Comment: So, from this I would conclude that it can only be expressed as a series of terms, and no simple formula can be derived.

Comment: @GiorgioBusoni Well, it's a _finite_ series.